# Jquery maskMoney mask function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, money-format, jquery-mask

When i set the 2.70 value on input i see result like 0.27 € where is my fail ?

this is my code ;

```
    $(input).maskMoney({thousands:',', decimal:'.', allowZero:false, suffix: ' €'});
$(input).maskMoney('mask', parseFloat(2.70));
```

Answer (score 0):

As this starts from the cent the decimal place. To return €2.70 you would need to pass in 270(cents).

Comment: If you want clients to enter 2.7 and it return 2.7 you can add the *100 in yourself

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I managed to solve a simple way, I hope it works for you.

```
let element =  document.getElementById('input');
let value = element.value;

value = parseFloat(valor.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
document.getElementById('input').value = value;
```